# How to change AppBarButton's style of MediaPlayerElement on xbox?

Tags: xaml, uwp, media-player

[image]

As the picture shows, I want to change `MediaPlayerElement`'s AppBarButton style, something like:

1. Button size, 2x is the best.
2. Remove default focus reveal border.
3. Change the Button to a circle, not rectangle.
4. When a button is focused, change it's background color.

I have followed the advice of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls, but found no idea.

Set `CornerRadius` will result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default style of `MediaTransportControls`, there is such a snippet:

```xml
<!-- New AppBar button style 48x48 pixels in size -->
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaButtonWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaButtonHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

If you want a round button, you can modify it like this

```xml
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20" />
</Style>
```

If you need to modify more styles, you need to create a copy of the style of the AppBarButton to adjust.

Because the default style code of `MediaTransportControls` is very large, I put the code of the default style [here](https://github.com/Richasy/Misc/tree/master/MediaTransportControlsDefaultStyle) (which also includes the code of `AppBarButtonRevealStyle`), you can modify it according to your needs.

---

**Update**

`AppBarButton` has its own internal height. If special handling is needed, you must first rewrite the style of `AppBarButton`

The main display content of `AppBarButton` is an Icon. In the default style, it is in the `ViewBox`. We can rewrite its height according to our needs.

You can find the modified code [here](https://github.com/Richasy/Misc/blob/master/MediaTransportControlsDefaultStyle/AppBarButtonChangedStyle.xml)

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}" Margin="-1,0">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox x:Name="ContentViewbox"
    Height="25"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Margin="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" >
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
        Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
    </Viewbox>
    ...
</Grid>
```

After modifying the code of `AppBarButton`, we also need to modify some styles of `MediaTransportControls`

```xml
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="True" />
</Style>

<!-- New CommandBar Style -->
<Style x:Key="CommandBarStyle" TargetType="CommandBar">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="90" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

You can finally get this effect:

[image: Imgur]

Best regards.

Comment: I tried, not work. See the picture in original question. And the link you provided is invalid.

Comment: Also, it seem I can't change `AppBarButton`'s height to 80. It seems the height is fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I have transferred the code files to the new repository, please check this [link](https://github.com/Richasy/Misc/tree/master/MediaTransportControlsDefaultStyle). `MediaTransportControls` does have height restrictions, this should be modifiable in the default style.

Comment: But `AppBarButton`'s height to 80, does not work in fact. I can also find the style in generic.xaml.

Comment: I followed your advice, rewrite `AppBarButton` in App.xaml, the icon just show half. https://wx4.sinaimg.cn/mw690/663b0491gy1gaxerv7t4mj20e003babv.jpg

Comment: Hi, If that doesn't work, try adding this code in **App.xaml** -> **<Application.Resources>**: `<x:Double x: Key ="AppBarThemeCompactHeight"> 90 </ x:Double>`